# Eliminar texto de un input type text antes de introducir otro

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy haciendo una pagina en la que introduces tu peso y un planeta del sistema solar y te saca tu peso con la gravedad del planeta seleccionado.

He creado unos botones que imprimen en un textview el nombre del planeta que se pulse,
el problema es que si pulso otro se escribe al lado, como puedo hacer que se borre el anterior si pulso otro?

Estos son los botones:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="4"><input name="planeta" class="planeta" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><img src="022-mercury.svg"  onclick="print('Mercurio')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Mercurio" title="Mercurio"></td>
   <td><img src="051-venus.svg" onclick="print('Venus')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Venus" title="Venus"></td>
   <td><img src="010-earth.svg" onclick="print('Tierra')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Tierra" title="Tierra"></td>
   <td><img src="021-mars.svg" onclick="print('Marte')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Marte" title="Marte"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><img src="016-jupiter.svg" onclick="print('Júpiter')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Júpiter" title="Júpiter"></td>
   <td><img src="036-saturn.svg" onclick="print('Saturno')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Saturno" title="Saturno"></td>
   <td><img src="050-uranus.svg" onclick="print('Urano')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Urano" title="Urano"></td>
   <td><img src="026-neptune.svg" onclick="print('Neptuno')" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Neptuno" title="Neptuno"></td>
</tr>
```

Y esta es la funcion que los imprime:

```
function print(planeta)
{
    document.form.planeta.value = document.form.planeta.value + planeta;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto simplemente he tenido que añadir esto a la funcion:

```
function print(planeta)
{
    document.form.planeta.value = "";
    document.form.planeta.value = document.form.planeta.value + planeta;
}
```